# Python GDAL, SetAttributeFilter not working

Tags: python-3.x, gis, gdal

I am trying to use GDAL's SetAttributeFilter() to filter the features in a layer of my shapefile, but the filter seems to have no effect.

My current data is a shapefile from the US Census Bureau, but I have tried with other shapefiles and get a similar result.

For example

```
from osgeo import ogr

shapefile_path = '../input/processed/shapefile/'
shapefile_ds = ogr.Open(shapefile_path)
cbsa = shapefile_ds.GetLayer('cb_2016_us_cbsa_500k')

print(cbsa.GetFeatureCount())

cbsa.SetAttributeFilter('NAME = "Chicago-Naperville-Elgin, IL-IN-WI"')
feat = cbsa.GetNextFeature()

print(feat.GetField('NAME'))
print(cbsa.GetFeatureCount())
```

Yields

```
945
Platteville, WI
945
```

I'm using Python 3.6 and GDAL 2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the return value of the `SetAttributeFilter` statement and make sure its 0, otherwise something went wrong.

In this particular case, its probably due to the quoting. Single quotes refer to string literals (a value), and double quotes refer to a column/table name.

Depending on how you run this Python code, somewhere in the stdout/stderr GDAL prints something like:
`ERROR 1: "Chicago-Naperville-Elgin, IL-IN-WI" not recognised as an available field.`

More details can be found at:
https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc52_strict_sql_quoting

To get it working, simply swap the single/double quoting, so:

`cbsa.SetAttributeFilter("NAME='Chicago-Naperville-Elgin, IL-IN-WI'")`

Comment: You are exactly right, I was getting a return value of 5 and swapping the quotes worked.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

While this was a while ago, when I learn something I like to say what worked in my case in case I search this again.

For me, I had to have the syntax like:

```
cbsa.SetAttributeFilter('"NAME" = \'Chicago-Naperville-Elgin\'')  # I didn't test multiple values
```

where the referenced page of the accepted answer says:

```
<delimited identifier>     ::= <double quote> <delimited identifier body> <double quote>
<character string literal> ::= <quote> [ <character representation> ... ] <quote>
```

It may be that there has been an update to ogr changing this since '17.